# how to include structures as header file

Tags: c++, header, structure

I am trying to create a header file for my structure, but after I created the structure and included it in the main program it gives me error messages.

this is my header file

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MYSTRUCT_H_INCLUDED
#define MYSTRUCT_H_INCLUDED

struct book{

 int bknum;
 string bname;
 string author;
};

#endif // MYSTRUCT_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Please add the error messages.

Comment: You dont need #pragma once and a header guard with ifndef and define. Chose one. I prefer ifndef

Comment: Aside from the error message, you are also missing a question.

Comment: Add `#include <string>` and change `string` to `std::string`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Without the error message I can only guess, but this is my guess as what needs to be corrected:

```
#include <string>

struct book{
 int bknum;
 std::string bname;
 std::string author;
};
```

Comment: Good guess. The inability of some posters to include error messages continues to amaze. As does the ability of responders to answer questions despite the lack of information.